# setOnKeyListener not responding in Kitkat 4.4 Quad Core Android Box

Tags: javascript, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am getting keycodes from Android box remote and sending it to my JavaScript function `onKeyEvent` for my own JavaScript navigation in App which I install in Quad Core Android Box with kitkat 4.4.2.

The below function is not responding here. It is, however, working fine in below versions tested in (4.0.3, 4.1.2 and 4.2.2).

```
mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "keycode = " + event.getKeyCode() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Jadoo4 Application", "Key Event" + event.getKeyCode());
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    if(isUserAccessEnabled)
                    {
                        switch(keyCode)
                        {
                           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                                if(mWebView.canGoBack()!=true && isInternetAvailable == true)
                                finish();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:onKeyEvent(" + event.getKeyCode() + ")");
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I get this error:

```
03-20 19:26:24.940: I/WindowManager(531): mapkey no map key list 03-20
19:26:25.010: D/RemoteIME(768): keycode: 22, realAction: false 03-20
19:26:25.310: I/WindowManager(531): mapkey no map key list 03-20
19:26:25.410: D/RemoteIME(768): keycode: 22, realAction: true 03-20
19:26:25.940: I/WindowManager(531): mapkey no map key list
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing / error you are getting ?

Comment: 03-20 19:26:24.940: I/WindowManager(531): mapkey no map key list
03-20 19:26:25.010: D/RemoteIME(768): keycode: 22, realAction: false
03-20 19:26:25.310: I/WindowManager(531): mapkey no map key list
03-20 19:26:25.410: D/RemoteIME(768): keycode: 22, realAction: true
03-20 19:26:25.940: I/WindowManager(531): mapkey no map key list

i am getting this output. log.d under tag "Jadoo4 Application" is not coming in output LogCat when i press different keys from remote